# Document management solution for Drupal

Tags: drupal, file

I am looking for a Drupal solution that permits the following functionality

- file upload to a secure directory - 
  secured by user or role
- allow user to embed uploaded files
  anywhere they want within a html
  'page' or 'story' node - not just a list of documents in the middle or end of the page.
- security - prevent non-authorized
  users from viewing, editing, deleting
  files. Also administrator is limited to viewing, editing,deleting 
  his/her own group of files.

modules such as upload and webfm seem to do good job at permitting upload to a node, however by rule, files are displayed at the bottom of the node.
This does not allow for much creative layout, such as mixing titles and text with download links. However this solution 
does allow you to secure files in that files cannot be viewed by anyone except for users with access to this node.

Another approach is to user an uploader added/contained within a text editor (eg: TINYMCE). This allows user to upload
and embed documents with an anchor tag/ However does not offer much security. Files can be possibly viewed by anyone on the internet,
and this offers little security that files cannot be viewed or deleted by any user with permission to use this feature.

Comment: Do you mean you've looked at webfm (I am not aware of filefm).

Comment: sorry corrected, filedepot also! http://drupal.org/project/filedepot, http://drupal.org/project/webfm

Comment: what limitation did you find with webfm?

Comment: very good product, but users want to be able to drop link to files anywhere in the document, like an href.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice list of options...
http://drupalmodules.com/category/File+management